# How can I use IronPython to save an analysis which I have modified using the Spotfire Consumer back to the library?

Tags: spotfire

Is it possible to save an analysis file that is opened in the Spotfire's Web Player (i.e. **Spotfire Consumer**) programmatically by calling some API or that is all handled by the UI (Web Player)? I am using Spotfire version 10.1

Example, can I do that:
[image]

... in code (e.g. using Web API)

Comment: it's not really clear what you're asking. could you edit your question to be more specific about what you're trying to do? please also list the version of Spotfire you're using.

Comment: @niko Thank you for your comment. I have added a bit more to help convey my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for the clarification!

the following IronPython code will save an analysis. you will find a limitation, however, when saving in the Web Player, that the dropdown in the upper right corner **must** be set to "Viewing" (in 10.0). to reiterate: you cannot use this code to save a document that is currently in "Editing" mode in the Web Player.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application import DocumentSaveSettings
from Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.Library import LibraryManager, LibraryItemType, LibraryItemMetadataSettings
from Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.ApplicationModel import ApplicationThread

def save_to_library(app, path, filename, meta, settings):
  def f():
    app.SaveAs(path, filename, meta, settings)
  return f

# path info
lib_path = "/path/to/file"
filename = "My Analysis"

# reference the LibraryManager
lm = Application.GetService[LibraryManager]()

# determine if the path exists
success, lib_folder = lm.TryGetItem(lib_path, LibraryItemType.Folder)

if success:
  # save the file
  Application.GetService[ApplicationThread]().InvokeAsynchronously(save_to_library(Application, lib_folder, filename, LibraryItemMetadataSettings(), DocumentSaveSettings()))
else:
  print "folder " + lib_path + " does not exist in the Library"
```

code based on [this article from the TIBCO Wiki](https://community.tibco.com/wiki/ironpython-script-save-file-locally-or-library-tibco-spotfire).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited my question as suggested. We are using Spotfire Consumer (i.e. Web Player) if that makes any difference and not using "Business Author". Preferably it will be better if we can achieve the same using C# API. 

Anyway, I have a question about this code, I am not sure how (if possible) this code can be run in the Web Player (I am sorry but I and my team are completely new to this eco-system).

Comment: sure, no worries :) I've been working with Spotfire for years and so maybe using some "archaic" terms haha. "Business author" is the component of Web Player which allows editing of an analysis through the browser. I believe the C# API would be a similar implementation, but I have much less experience with C#. you can view the API docs at https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/sfire_dev/area/doc/api/TIB_sfire-analyst_api/Index.aspx

Comment: Thanks, will have a look. Yes, it was confusing when I found out (it was a few days ago) that there are a new name and an old one for some of the products :D. Anyway, I had a look at the API. The problem is I don't have an idea on where this can be run. How to execute that code in the docs on an analysis file - is it through the desktop client - Spotfire Analyst?

Comment: the site I linked above provides the documentation for all of the classes and their members that are exposed to the C# and IronPython APIs. for example, `Spotfire.Dxp.Application.DocumentSaveSettings` corresponds to this doc: https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/sfire_dev/area/doc/api/TIB_sfire-analyst_api/html/T_Spotfire_Dxp_Application_DocumentSaveSettings.htm . the following wiki article has some info and examples about implementing the APIs: https://community.tibco.com/wiki/tibco-spotfire-c-extensions-overview

Comment: Thank you" Will try to use the API tomorrow at work. That helps a lot :)

Comment: I had a look at the available C# and IronPython APIs. However, based on my reading so far, it does not seem possible to execute code (e.g. C#) on the Spotfire Consumer/WebPlayer. It seems to be possible to execute the code only in the Spotfire Consumer. Could you please let me know if I have missed something from the docs? Thank you in advance! :)